# "Encountering 'minDash.isArray is not a function' Error with Camunda Platform Properties Panel in bpmn-js React TypeScript Project"

Tags: reactjs, camunda, bpmn.io, bpmn-js, camunda-spin

It appears that you're encountering an error with the Camunda Platform Properties Panel module in your React TypeScript project. The error message "minDash.isArray is not a function" suggests there might be an issue with how you're using the module.Error Description: When attempting to utilize the Camunda Platform Properties Panel module, an error occurs stating that "minDash.isArray is not a function".Repetition: Even after dismissing the error message, the issue persists, preventing you from effectively using the flow diagram. Environment: You're working with React TypeScript and utilizing the following versions: bpmn-js: v17.0.2 bpmn-js-properties-panel: v5.13.0

[image]